# jQueryUI add click function for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page with some number of info dialog boxes (5 in this example).  The objective is to have a variable number of info boxes on a page each called by a unique button.  When the button is clicked, any other box is closed and the current box appears. Instead of trying to keep track of which box was opened or about to open, I thought I'd simply close all the boxes and open the current info box.

The code below works: the first for loop initializes all of the dialog boxes and the closeBoxes() function closes any dialog that's open before opening the assigned dialog box.  However it seems like I should be able to loop through the .click(function()..) and add any number of info boxes.  I've tried $("#btn"+i)...("#info"+i) in a loop, but that simply doesn't work.

```
var TotalInfoBoxes=5;
for ( var i=1; i<=TotalInfoBoxes; i++) {
    $("#info"+i).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
}

$("#btn1").click(function() { closeBoxes(); $("#info1").dialog( "open" ); });
$("#btn2").click(function() { closeBoxes(); $("#info2").dialog( "open" ); });
$("#btn3").click(function() { closeBoxes(); $("#info3").dialog( "open" ); });
$("#btn4").click(function() { closeBoxes(); $("#info4").dialog( "open" ); });
$("#btn5").click(function() { closeBoxes(); $("#info5").dialog( "open" ); });

function closeBoxes() {
    for (var i=1; i<=TotalInfoBoxes; i++){
        $("#info"+i).dialog("close");
    }
}
```

The dialog box is an elegant solution, but I need some more generic code as I may have 20 or 30 info boxes on a given page.  Greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for close dialog box simple use by this all dialog box close

they all inherit the same class, this is the best way to select all and close by:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Comment: This is a much better approach than looping through and closing each item.  
Seems like that would work for: 
    for ( var i=1; i<=TotalInfoBoxes; i++) {
        $("#info"+i).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    }

Comment: thanks @user2738642 if you like up then another visitor use this

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the buttons and dialogs have a common class say *btn* for buttons &  *info* for your dialogs

```
$(".btn").on('click',function(e){
     closeBoxes();
     var index=$(this).index();
     $(".info:eq("+index+")").dialog("open");      
});
```

Comment: Excellent.  Combine this with Rituraj Ratan's comment and I have a much better solution.

Comment: @user2738642 glad to hear :)